Flutter build fail because of razorpay package name conflict after upgrading to flutter version 3.24.0
After day one of upgrading Flutter to Flutter version 3.24.0, I suddenly started getting build issues because of the conflict with the Razorpay package name 'com.razorpay'.
Below is the error log
[com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.40] /Users/..../.gradle/caches/transforms-3/8865b1e92255561aafb98c9aa637d5cd/transformed/jetified-checkout-1.6.40/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Package name 'com.razorpay' used in: com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.40, com.razorpay:standard-core:1.6.40.
/Users/neerdev/Desktop/flutter_workspace/..../..../android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDevelopmentDebugMainManifest'.

I tried below approaches with no luck. Build is still failing.

Tried by upgrading the razorpay library to razorpay_flutter 1.3.7.
Tried repairing or even deleting the cache.
Tried the commond 'fvm flutter pub upgrade'


pubspec.yaml

    publish_to: none
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.19.0 <4.0.0"
      flutter: 3.24.0
    
    dependencies:
      bloc: ^8.1.1
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_web_plugins:
        sdk: flutter
      flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2
      flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
      firebase_auth: ^4.19.5
      firebase_core: ^2.24.2
      firebase_auth_platform_interface: ^7.2.6
      firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.7
      firebase_messaging: ^14.6.9
      firebase_core_platform_interface: ^5.0.0
      firebase_analytics: ^10.5.1
      firebase_remote_config: ^4.2.7
      firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.3.7
      intl: ^0.18.1
      basic_utils: ^5.2.2
      cached_network_image: ^3.3.0
      connectivity_plus: ^6.0.3
      date_format: ^2.0.6
      dio: ^4.0.6
      fhir: ^0.9.0
      fhir_at_rest: ^0.9.0
      file_picker: ^8.0.3
      equatable: ^2.0.5
      flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
      flutter_image_compress: ^2.0.4
      flutter_keyboard_visibility: ^6.0.0
      flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
      get_it: ^7.2.0
      getwidget: ^4.0.0
      google_fonts: ^5.1.0
      google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0
      google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.5
      google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
      http: ^1.0.0
      http_interceptor: ^1.0.2
      jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk: ^0.4.2
      json_annotation: ^4.6.0
      json_serializable: ^6.3.1
      local_auth: ^2.1.2
      location: ^6.0.2
      maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
      mime: ^1.0.2
      oauth2_client: ^3.0.0
      palette_generator: ^0.3.3+2
      path: ^1.6.4
      path_provider: ^2.0.11
      path_provider_android: ^2.2.0
      permission_handler: ^11.0.0
      provider: ^6.0.3
      razorpay_flutter: ^1.3.7
      shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
      url_launcher: ^6.1.5
      uuid: ^3.0.6
      validators: ^3.0.0
      age_calculator: ^1.0.0
      auth_buttons: ^3.0.2
      package_info_plus: ^4.2.0
      webview_flutter: ^4.7.0
      flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.14.6
      collection: ^1.15.0-nullsafety.4
      wello_auth:
        path: ../wello_auth
      device_info_plus: ^10.1.0
      random_string: ^2.3.1
      image_picker: ^1.0.4
      upgrader: ^10.3.0
      theme_provider: ^0.6.0
      responsive_grid: ^2.1.0
      infinite_listview: ^1.1.0
      animated_icon_button: ^1.0.2
      badges: ^3.1.2
      gradient_slider: ^1.0.2
      fl_chart: ^0.68.0
      community_charts_flutter: ^1.0.4
      chewie: ^1.3.5
      date_picker_timeline: ^1.2.5
      date_picker_timeline_fixed: ^2.0.0
      expandable: ^5.0.1
      fancy_shimmer_image: ^2.0.2
      floating_action_bubble: ^1.1.4
      flutter_cupertino_date_picker_fork: ^1.0.6
      table_calendar: ^3.0.8
      flutter_calendar_carousel: ^2.4.3
      calendar_date_picker2: ^1.1.5
      flutter_full_pdf_viewer_null_safe: ^1.0.0
      pdf: ^3.8.3
      advance_pdf_viewer:
        git:
          url: git@github.com:lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer.git
          ref: 4e5d96be29de515f1081c0b6897741b8dca84722
      flutter_shimmer: ^2.1.2
      flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
      rflutter_alert: ^2.0.7
      shimmer: ^3.0.0
      sprintf: ^7.0.0
      flutter_svg: ^2.0.7
      flutter_swiper_view: ^1.1.8
      font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
      percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
      pin_code_fields: ^8.0.1
      pin_input_text_field: ^4.2.0
      auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
      expandable_text: ^2.3.0
      sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2
      super_tooltip: ^2.0.7
      timeline_tile: ^2.0.0
      version_banner: ^1.0.0-nullsafety.0
      video_player: null
      youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.1
      another_flushbar: ^1.12.29
      fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
      another_xlider: ^3.0.1
      search_choices: ^2.1.1
      roundcheckbox: ^2.0.5
      flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.10
      flutter_sound_lite: ^8.5.0
      flutter_chat_bubble: ^2.0.2
      flutter_chat_ui: ^1.6.6
      dash_chat_2: ^0.0.15
      pkce: ^1.1.0+1
      app_settings: ^5.1.1
    
    dev_dependencies:
      bloc_test: ^9.1.1
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      mocktail: ^1.0.1
      build_runner: ^2.2.0
      very_good_analysis: ^5.1.0
      flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1
    
    dependency_overrides:
      http: ^0.13.4
      intl: ^0.17.0
    
    flutter_native_splash:
      color: "#ffffff"
      background_image: "assets/images/ic_launcher_round.png"
    
    flutter_icons:
      android: "launcher_icon"
      ios: true
      image_path: "assets/images/ic_launcher_round.png"
      min_sdk_android: 21
    
    flutter:
      uses-material-design: true
      generate: true
      assets:
        - assets/lang/
        - assets/images/
        - assets/images/emojis/
        - assets/conf/
        - assets/pdfs/

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        // START: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // END: FlutterFire Configuration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

